# Lightning Events: how to get the name of an Application event in the handler

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I want to have one method for ALL events. In that method, I need to dispatch the event-name and whatever detail I can get about the event. The way I'm trying it, all seems to be empty (s. Result). Is there a way to get any information about an event inside a generic handler/dispatcher?

**Markup**

```
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.events}" />
```

**Controller**

```
events : function(cmp, evt, hlp){
    console.log('LTNG :: ',evt.getName(),evt.getParams());
},
```

**Result**

[image]

**Expected**

At least evt.getName() should NOT be *undifined*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the name of the event is not guaranteed to be present so I don't see a way to reliably distinguish between events in a common handler. This is especially true for Application level events over Component events.

As a workaround you can have a separate handler for each event, but have it simply be a passthrough to a common handler where you include the event name.

**Markup**

```
<aura:handler event="force:foo" action="{!c.fooHandler}" />
<aura:handler event="force:bar" action="{!c.barHandler}" />
```

**Controller**

```
fooHandler: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    helper.events(event, "force:foo");
},
barHandler: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    helper.events(event, "force:bar");
}
```

And the `events` function in your helper has the common event handling logic.

Comment: Thanks, Trevor, as always for your qualified feedbacks. Good idea for the workaround and I will use it. Would be great, if you at Salesforce could consider to extend appliaction events, so that they carry a bit more information with them then now (Name, FiredBy, etc.) This would be super-helpful.